# C# remove the timer (Monogame)

Tags: c#, performance, monogame

I have made a game in C# (Monogame) but the game is running too slow. Is there a way too remove the timer so that the program runs as fast as the computer can handle?

Comment: MonoGame will, by default, target 60 frames per second. If you're seeing less than that it may not be related to any timer put in place by MG. Can you provide more detail on the performance issues you are seeing as well as information about what you are attempting to update/draw in a game loop?

Comment: Yeah, that's the issue, the FPS is locked at 60 according to my FPS counter. There are probably no issues with the performance but only that Monogame locks the program at 60 FPS like you said. Is there a way to remove this limit?

Comment: The Game class should have a IsFixedTimeStep prop you can set to false. This should remove the 60 FPS cap.

Comment: There was no IsFixedTimeStep inside Game1.cs so I added one inside the Game class. Instead of locking the game at 60 FPS it is now locked at 144 instead. (Because of my monitor). I typed IsFixedTimeStep = false;. Is that correct? How do I remove the 144 FPS limit now?

Comment: Nevermind, I solved it. I had to add this aswell:

graphics.SynchronizeWithVerticalRetrace = false;
graphics.ApplyChanges();

Everything is working now, thank you for your help!